# Rails: dependent: :destroy based on multiple keys

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, notifications

I have a model `Notification` that belongs to a `User`. A `Notification` has the attributes `user_id` and `notified_by_id`, which contain unique `User` id's, with `user_id` representing the user that is receiving the notification and `notified_by_id` referring to the user that created the notification.

When a `User` is deleted, I want to destroy notifications that it created as well as notifications that it has received. In my `User` model, I specify the destroy dependency:

```
has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy
```

However, this only destroys `Notifications` that have a `user_id` matching the deleted `User`. Those notifications created by the deleted `User` (those with `notified_by_id` equal to `User.id`) are not deleted.

How can I specify a destroy dependency based on two fields? Should I use a before_destroy instead like below?

```
before_destroy :clean_notifications

  def clean_notifications
    Notification.where(notified_by_id: self.id).destroy_all
  end
```

I can solve the immediate problem this way, but I believe there is a more proper way of doing it. Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add one more line in user.rb

```
has_many :incoming_notifications, class_name: "Notification",
                      foreign_key: "notified_by_id", dependent: :destroy
```